# Change Document template path in multiple Word Templates

Tags: c#, vba, ms-word

I have about 500 word documents that I need to change the server name in the Document template path.  I am not an expert with VBA but I have tried several [solutions](http://www.edugeek.net/forums/scripts/35199-vba-script-change-word-document-template-location.html) that have not worked for me.  Is there a way to do this (perhaps with C#, with a foreach loop on the directory?) that I can do a very simple find and replace on this field ?

i.e.

```
\\ASDCFS\NtierFiles\...
```

becomes

```
\\NewServer\NtierFiles\...
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write to the field in the dialog box directly. In the object model the equivalent is Document.AttachedTemplate and yes, you can work with that. Using in the object model (whether using VBA or C#) you'd loop the documents in a folder, open each in Word, assign the correct path, save and close.

More efficient and less prone to "hiccups" if the original template path is already invalid, would be to edit the documents' Word Open XML directly, without using the Word application. The Open XML SDK would be a good tool for this. It provides the AttachedTemplate class (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.attachedtemplate(v=office.14).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can use WTC to correct the template path in a bulk of documents. You find the source code and binary on Github: https://github.com/NeosIT/wtc

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?